# How to combine Zabbix with MariaDB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, zabbix, mariadb

Ubuntu Server 13.04; Zabbix actual version from source code; MariaDB 5.5

Fistly I've download and unpack Zabbix source code. After that:

```
./configure --enable-server --enable-agent --with-mysql --enable-ipv6 --with-net-snmp --with-libcurl
```

But an error occurs. From log:

```
configure:7488: checking for mysql_config 
configure:7521: result: no 
configure:7719: error: MySQL library not found
```

How can I fix that? For example, phpmyadmin see libmysql - 5.5.31-MariaDB and I have libmysqlclient18 installed too:

```
libmysqlclient18 is already the newest version.
libmysqlclient18 set to manually installed.
```

Try to force define path to libs:

```
--with-mysql=/usr/lib/
```

Server answer:

```
checking for mysql_config... /usr/lib/
./configure: line 7529: /usr/lib/: Is a directory
./configure: line 7531: /usr/lib/: Is a directory
```

I don't really know if it's error or just warning and it already found library.

Trying to install -dev packet:

```
mammuthus@server:~/zabbix-2.0.6$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.13.04.1) but 5.5.31+maria-1~raring is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Okay

```
mammuthus@server:~/zabbix-2.0.6$ sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libmysqlclient18 is already the newest version.
```

So i already have -dev tools, yep?

Comment: @dawud, I have 2 official mariaDB repositories in my list (US and RU mirrors), but I have not any libmariadbclient-dev packet in it. I will manualy download it from url you provided and install.

Comment: Hm, I was wrong, libmariadbdclient-dev is in repository. I try to install it, but - libmariadbclient-dev is already the newest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the development headers for MariaDB.

Provided you are using the [MariaDB repositories](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/) for Ubuntu 13, try installing
[libmariadbdclient-dev](http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-5.5/libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.31%2bmaria-1~raring_amd64.deb) from that repository.

You could even manually download the `*-dev` package from [one of the mirrors](http://mirror2.hs-esslingen.de/mariadb/repo/5.5/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-5.5/) to check it:

```
# atool -l libmariadbclient-dev_5.5.31+maria-1~raring_amd64.deb | grep mysql_config
-rwxr-xr-x root/root      6764 2013-05-22 01:48 ./usr/bin/mysql_config
-rw-r--r-- root/root      2127 2013-05-22 02:20 ./usr/share/man/man1/mysql_config.1.gz
```

For comprehensive instructions on how to build a **package** from the upstream Zabbix sources check [here](https://zabbix.org/wiki/Docs/howto/rebuild_debs).

Comment: $ sudo aptitude install build-essentials devscripts quilt - from link is solution. Thank you.